# Maximum return value of arc4random()

Tags: ios, arc4random

For some reason I'm not able to find any sort of official doc telling me what the range is for `arc4random()`. I've seen in some non-authoritative sources that it's 2^32 - 1, a little over 4 billion.

Can anyone confirm this? If so, can you link to an official doc showing this number somewhere? I'm trying to generate a random number on my iOS app and need to have a pretty official upper end for the algorithm to work correctly.

Comment: [this source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) is not "authoritarian" enough?

Comment: Same page within 10 seconds by googling `arc4random`, top link (Apple) says *"The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right,

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>  The arc4random() function uses the key stream generator employed by the arc4 cipher, which uses 8*8 8
>  bit S-Boxes.  The S-Boxes can be in about (2**1700) states.  The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random pseudorandom
>  random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1, and therefore has twice the range of rand(3) and
>  random(3).
> ```
>
> arc4random_buf() function fills the region buf of length nbytes with
>   ARC4-derived random data.
>
> arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random
>   number less than upper_bound.  arc4random_uniform() is recommended
>   over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids 
>   "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.
>
> The arc4random_stir() function reads data from /dev/urandom and uses
>   it to permute the S-Boxes via  arc4random_addrandom().
>
> There is no need to call arc4random_stir() before using arc4random()
>   functions family, since they auto-matically automatically  matically
>   initialize themselves.

Source https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html

Comment: Can you add something of your own to this copy-paste? Even fixing the formatting and highighting the relevant phrase would be a start.

Answer (score 3):

The [man page for arc4random](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) says:

> The `arc4random()` function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to 2<sup>32</sup> – 1…

And, happily, this matches its return type of `uint32_t`. That is, `arc4random` may return *any* 32-bit unsigned integer. The inclusive upper bound is `UINT32_MAX` (or `UInt32.max` in Swift).

**However,** if you just need numbers uniformly distributed within a particular range, you should use **`arc4random_uniform(n)`** (the range is exclusive: `arc4random_uniform(5)` can return 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4). This is more correct — and more convenient! — than using `%` to truncate the range returned by regular `arc4random()`.